# Element @ids are stripped from apk

Tags: android, automated-tests, appium, seetest

I am performing automated testing of an android application and I would like to select elements by `@id`. I have been using a proprietary software called SeeTest Automation because it performs "instrumentation" to allow selection by `@id`s. I'd like to switch to Appium, but I can't figure out how to select elements by `@id`.

When I view the app layout from uiautomateviewer, elements do not have `@id`s. How do I ensure I can select elements by `@id` from Appium?

Answer (score 0):

UIautomatorviewer and appium inspector display element id with resource-id field. If you share screenshot of your uiautomatireviewer or appium inspector then I can tell you exact id for the element.